# GUI Performance impact of minification = false?

Tags: gui-extensions

What is the performance impact of turning minification in the GUI to false?  I am asking because I have a GUI extension that breaks when minification is enabled but works fine when it is turned off.

Would it be slower on the first load and then just as fast as minification = true for all future loads?  Or, would it impact the loading time of the GUI for every window all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anecdotally I have found it to be significantly slower particularly on initial page load and with a "real" environment (i.e not on a VM). However I wouldn't say it was unusably slow.

It sounds like you have a syntax error in your javascript which the minifier is producing valid but not working javascript for. I suggest trying to fix your JS if you can.

Comment: The js console does not have any errors or warnings in the console.  Which minification approach does the Tridion GUI follow?  Maybe I can look at known issues with that minifier?

Comment: New question posted about the minifier:  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/what-minifier-does-the-tridion-gui-use

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the size of your JS, if it is just 50 ~ 100 lines of script, the effect might not even be noticeable but if it is thousands of line, then yes, the impact would be significant and for every window (not all the time but each time it is not getting loaded from the Cache).

Moreover, if you accessing it from resource intensive devices like phones and tablets, then the gain of minification would be greatly enhanced.

As Rob is suggesting, my suggestion will also be to fix the JS and run it with minification=true.