# What minifier does the Tridion GUI use?

Tags: gui-extensions

What is the minifier that the Tridion GUI uses?  I have an issue where my GUI Extension code works fine without minification but does not work with the minifer enabled.  Maybe there are certain coding styles or standards that need to be followed for the Tridion GUI minifier to work properly?

[This is related to another question here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/gui-performance-impact-of-minification-false)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an implementation detail that you shouldn't really have to deal with. 
But I believe Tridion 2013 uses version 3.30 of the [Microsoft Ajax Minifier.](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)

Comment: True - but some minifiers break in certain 'valid' js (although that 'valid' js does not follow best coding practices).  For example, this interesting debate with Douglas Crockford over JSMin rules, https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057

Comment: I have had Javascript in GUI extensions stop working when minified so I think this detail is quite useful thanks!